# Best way to store a ztable in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to calculate p-values for a bunch of metrics on null matrices. I've written functions to get the standard deviation and zvalue. In order to get the p-value I need to look up the zscore in a [ztable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table).

My question is, what is the best way to store this table in c++? In python I would probably keep the table in something like a dictionary so I could access it like this: ztable["0.1"]["0.03"] for a zscore of 0.13. Or even better, ztable["0.13"]. Thanks!

Side note: it's been a while since I had a stats class, if there's a better way to calculate p-values I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: if `ztable["0.13"]` works to you, why not the same in C++ using a map?

Comment: I'm not familiar with map, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use `map<pair<double,double>, double>` and round all keys to 3 significant digits, e.g. for your example:

```
map<pair<double,double>, double> ztable;
ztable[make_pair(0.1,0.03)] = 0.13;
```

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question better, you could just use `map<double,double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two-dimensional array to store the data since looking at Wikipedia I can see that the data in a ztable is two-dimensional.  If I remember correctly this would be a pointer to a pointer, right?

Comment: I've thought about something like this, the only problem is I'd have to come up with some kind of system to translate 0.13 to coordinates in the array. I think this would work but it seems a bit cumbersome.